# Regex Match Inside matching

Tags: html, regex, visual-studio, notepad++

I have some trouble with a regex.
I need to extrapolate this part of text inside a long HTML page:

```
<li class="menuItem">
    <a class="menuItem" href="/site/ContactUs.aspx?section=510">
        <span class="posNR">3.
        </span>Contact Us<span class="shortDesc"></span><span class="line"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Another problem is that I have some string formatted like this:

```
<li class="menuItem"><a class="menuItem" href="/site/ContactUs.aspx?section=510"><span class="posNR">3.</span>Contact Us<span class="shortDesc"></span><span class="line"></span></a></li>
```

And in some other parts I have this:

```
<li class="menuItem">
              <a class="menuItem" href="/site/ContactUs.aspx?section=510">
                <span class="posNR">3.
                                </span>Contact Us<span class="shortDesc"></span><span class="line"></span></a>
            </li>
```

I want to extract this specific part from, for example, here:

```
        <li class="menuItem">
          <a class="menuItem" href="/site/News.aspx?section=316&amp;ViewType=Actual&amp;IdType=316">
            <span class="posNR">2.
                            </span>News<span class="shortDesc"></span><span class="line"></span></a>
      asdsdasda  </li>


        <li class="menuItem">
          <a class="menuItem" href="/site/ContactUs.aspx?section=510">
            <span class="posNR">3.
                            </span>Contact Us<span class="shortDesc"></span><span class="line"></span></a>
        </li>


      </ul>
```

Until now, I have tried some REGEX, like

```
(<li*[\s\S]*?<\/li>)
```

**I am using this regex in notepad ++ and/or Visual Studio Code.**

Comment: Regex isn't the best way to extract html or xml data. Nonetheless, what problem are you getting with your regex? What case is incorrectly matching?

Comment: Thank you for a reply. I need to match only the part with "Contact Us" (like the first snippet) in a long list of <li items

Comment: How about: `(<li(?:(?!<li)[\s\S])*?ContactUs[\s\S]*?<\/li>)`? Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/PcNyOE/1/)

Comment: It's perfect, thank you! Nonetheless, I don't understand how this part `(?:(?!<li)[\s\S])` works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
(<li(?:(?!<li)[\s\S])*?ContactUs[\s\S]*?<\/li>)
```

This pattern makes use of a tempered greedy token solution by tempering the `[\s\S]` to not allow `<li` i.e `(?:(?!<li)[\s\S])*`. You can read more about it [here and when to use it.](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed)

- `<li` matches starting literal `<li`
- `(?:(?!<li)[\s\S])*?` lazy non-capturing group that has a negative looahead `(?!` which makes sure another `<li` isn't present in the match. This has been added so that `<li... <li... </li>` doesn't match the whole thing but only from the second `<li>`
- `ContactUs` matches literal since condition states that `ContactUs` must be present in the matching `li`
- `[\s\S]*?` to match any characters (lazily)
- `<\/li>` to match closing `</li>`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PcNyOE/1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you again, it helped a lot!